# Entity Framework code first - foreign key relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, ef-code-first

I'm using ASP.NET MVC identity and attempting to create additional tables using the code first approach. My primary table for example is called `Orders`, this is referenced back to the `AspNetUsers` table (id) and multiple orders per user can be stored. A separate ID in the primary table will link to further order details in secondary tables.

I'm struggling how to implement the relationship between the two tables? If someone could please help, thanks

```
Public Class ApplicationUser
Inherits IdentityUser
    Public Overridable Property Orders() As Orders
End Class

Public Class Orders
   Public Property Id As String   'Should link to Id in AspNetUsers Table
   Public Property TimeandDate As Datetime
   Public Property OrderNo As Integer
   Public Overridable Property OrderLineDetail() As ICollection(Of OrderLineDetail)
End Class

Public Class OrderLineDetail
   Public Property Description As String
   Public Property Price As Decimal
End class

Public Class ApplicationDbContext
    Inherits IdentityDbContext(Of ApplicationUser)

    Public Sub New()
         MyBase.New("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema:=False)
    End Sub

    Public Property Orders() As DbSet(Of Orders)

    Public Shared Function Create() As ApplicationDbContext
        Return New ApplicationDbContext()
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Why don´t you just [google](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) the title of your question? You will find alot of material regarding data annotations and conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in ur AspNetUsers table:

```
  Public Property Orders As ICollection(Of Orders)
        Get
        End Get
        Set
        End Set
    End Property
```